# Difficulty understanding this definition of Galois extensions

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm having some trouble understanding the definition of a Galois group given in class. It says that a field extension $E/F$ is a Galois extension if its group of automorphisms is such that $Fix(Aut(E/F))=F$, in other words they fix exactly the ground field.

But consider the extension $\Bbb Q( \sqrt[3]{2})/\Bbb Q$. Clearly, this is not a Galois extension, as it's not normal, but all of its automorphism still fix the ground field?

What am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: The fixed field of the automorphism group here is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$, not $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah because it only contains the trivial automorphism , I was confused for  a moment , Thank you :)

Comment: This is, by the way, the best definition of being Galois, at least in my opinion. It’s the *correct* definition, I would even argue: It designates Galois extensions to be those fixed by the [Galois connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_connection) between field extensions and automorphism subgroups, thus designating them to be exactly the lattice of fields, for which Galois correspondenc is avalid. This definition therefore also works directly for infinite field extensions, without making any amendments.